# Question “How do you call a subsequence of consecutive elements ?”

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Question: [How do you call a subsequence of consecutive elements ?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5470/how-do-you-call-a-subsequence-of-consecutive-elements)

I guess that many people working in TCS have once wished for concise and unambiguous terms for “contiguous subsequence” and “not necessarily contiguous (but still order-preserving) subsequence,” and therefore the question is reasonably interesting to TCS researchers.  I believe that this question should be on topic in a similar sense that soft questions are on topic.

Comment: I'll wait to see what others say. I'm happy to open the question if there is consensus.

Comment: I agree with Tsuyoshi: it's not off-topic. Unfortunately, I don't know whether there are any good answers.

Comment: By popular demand, I reopened the question.

Comment: @Dave: Can you post your last comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By popular demand, I reopened the question.